# Issue when inserting Chinese data with code first and mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, cjk

I've done a project in ASP.NET MVC 3 using Mysql. To create a database, I use code first ef 4.1. Some of the data I insert in my database is Chinese characters. When I insert the data, it appears with `????`. I set my `connectionString` in my web config like this:

```
add name="mydbcontext" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root; password=; database=mydbcontext; pooling=false; charset=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
```

But the problem's still there... This is the way I use to insert the data:

```
public class MyMenu {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string AppForSmartphone { get; set; }
    public string Games { get; set; }
    public string Softwares { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string News { get; set; }
    public string Cart { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
     public DbSet<MyMenu> MyMenus { get; set; }
     public MyDbContext()
        : base("MyDbContext") {
    }
 }
   private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
   MyMenu tmpmenu = new MyMenu {
     About = 關於,
     Id = 1,
     Cart = 車,
     News = 新聞,
     AppForSmartphone = 應用程序的智能手機,
     Games = 遊戲,
     Softwares = 軟件,
     Home = 家,
     Language = ""
   };
    db.MyMenus.Add(tmpmenu);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: page encoding?  are you using nvarchar() in DB?

Comment: no, i use longtext, so on, my database is autogenerated , so i don't know how to do ???

Answer (score 1):

There is no Issue in your code.You just need to check the **DataType** of the column in which you are saving the data which is in Chinese.I guess you have used **varchar()** , rather you should be using **nvarchar()**.

I had the same issue a day back. And changing the datatype to nvarchar() fixed my issue.

**MySql does support multilingual.**
Changing the DataType should fix your issue.

Regards.

Comment: ok, but i forgot to say something, my database is autogenerated, so i don't know how to make that my database be well created without issues if you encounter the same problem in the past, pliz, tell me how to fix that